# Clarification for the definition of "a term is free for a variable in some wf. of a first order language"

Tags: logic, formal-languages

> **Definition 1** Let $A$ be any wf. of a first order language *L* and $x$ be any variable. We say $x$ occurs free in $A$ if there is at least one occurrence of $x$ in $A$ which is not the scope of $(\forall x)$.
>
> **Definition 2** Let $A$ be any wf. of a first order language *L*. A term $t$ is *free* for $x$ in $A$, if $x$ does not occur free in $A$ within the scope of a $(\forall y)$, where $y$ is any variable occurring in $t$.

I feel quite confused about the second definition. I was wondering if there's no $(\forall y)$ occurring in $A$, then how does the definition work?

In the textbook, there's an example, say, "the term $f_1^2(x_1,x_3)$ is free for $x_1$ in $(\forall x_2)A_1^2(x_1,x_2)\Rightarrow A_1^1(x_1)$ but is not free for $x_1$ in $(\forall x_3)(\forall x_2)A_1^2(x_1,x_2)\Rightarrow A_1^1(x_1).$"

For the first part, there is no $(\forall x_1)$ or $(\forall x_3)$ occurring in the wf. $(\forall x_2)A_1^2(x_1,x_2)\Rightarrow A_1^1(x_1)$. (Here $x_1$ occurs free in the wf.) So, for the definition, if there's no $(\forall y)$ in the wf. $A$, where $y$ is any variable occurring in $t$, then "$t$ is free for $x$ in $A$" automatically true? But this rule does not work for the second part of the example.

I can understand that the results of this example are reasonable, since the aim of the second definition is that $t$ may be substituted for every free occurrence of $x$ in $A$ without introducing any interactions with quantifiers in $A$. But I am really confused about how to use this definition.

Could you help me clarify this definition?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no $(\forall y)$ in the formula, then in particular there is no free $x$ within the scope of such a $(\forall y)$, so the condition is vacuously satisfied.

The textual definition of "free for $x$" is not very carefully worded with respect the use of "a" and "any". What is meant, in pseudo-formal notation, is something like:

> Let $A$ be any wf. A term $t$ is *free* for $x$ in $A$, iff
>
> ($\forall$variable "$y$" free in $t$)
> ($\forall$quantifier "$(\forall y)$" in $A$)
> $\neg$ ($\exists$appearance of $x$ free in $A$)
> this "$x$" is in the scope of the "$(\forall y)$").

An universal quantification over an empty set is always true, so if there is no $(\forall y)$ in $A$, then the condition "($\forall$quantifier "$(\forall y)$" in $A$)" is automatically satisfied, without even looking at $x$s.

Comment: Thanks! I am curious about why this definition works so well for its aim. I don't really understand it. But it seems that it provides reasonable results every time... Could you explain why we define "a term is free for a variable" in this way? Thanks again.

Comment: One way to think about it is to imagine $t$ and $A$ initially sitting beside each other, in some shared but unspecified context that presumably gives some meaning to the $y$s. Then substituting $t$ for $x$ in $A$ means that for each _free_ occurrence of $x$ in $A$ we create a _copy_ of $t$ and move that copy down to the $x$ along $A$'s abstract syntax tree. If we meet any $(\forall y)$ along the way down to $x$, the meaning of the free $y$ in the copy of $t$ would _change_ as it the copy moves inside the $(\forall y)$ scope -- and it is that change we don't want to happen.

Comment: On the other hand, I cannot explain the particular choice of the words "is free for" to name of the concept. It feels rather unintuitive to me -- but I'm not a native speaker of English, so who am I to complain?

Comment: As a native English speaker who found this after encountering the same problem, rest assured it is deeply unintuitive terminology regardless of one's language familiarity. Thank you for the illustration.

Answer (score 2):

In your examples regarding *substitutability* [from Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to mathematical logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0412808307) (4ed - 1997), Example 2, page 54], we have that :

> "the term $f^2_1(x_1,x_3)$ is free for $x_1$ in $(∀x_2)A^2_1(x_1,x_2) ⇒ A^1_1(x_1)$
>
> but is **not** free for $x_1$ in $(∀x_3)(∀x_2)A^2_1(x_1,x_2) ⇒ A^1_1(x_1)$."

As you says correctly, for the first part, there is no $(∀x_1)$ or $(∀x_3)$ occurring in the formula; thus, there is no possibility that the free occurrences of $x_1$ and $x_3$ in the *term* $f^2_1(x_1,x_3)$ are "captured" by a quantifier with the substitution, altering the "menaing" of the formula.

Why the *substitution* is not allowed with :

> $(∀x_3)(∀x_2)A^2_1(x_1,x_2) ⇒ A^1_1(x_1)$ ?

Because in this case the free occurrence of $x_3$ in the *term* $f^2_1(x_1,x_3)$, after substitution, would be "captured" by the quantifier $(∀x_3)$.

The resulting formula would be :

> $(∀x_3)(∀x_2)A^2_1(f^2_1(x_1,x_3),x_2) ⇒ A^1_1(x_1)$

generating a "constraint" on the term which is unwanted.

To see what happens without the above restriction, consider as interpretation of our language the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural numbers* and consider the simple formula [here $\le$ is a *binary* predicate which takes the place of $A^2_1$] :

> $\exists x (x \le y)$.

This formula is always *true* in $\mathbb N$; if we substitute $y$ with $0, 1, 2, \ldots$ we obtain the formulae :

> $\exists x (x \le 0), \exists x (x \le 1), \exists x (x \le 2), \ldots$

which are all satisfied for $x=0$.

Consider now a *term* $S(x)$ of our language, where $S$ is the function "successor" (thus: $S(x)$ is $x+1$).

Again, if we substitute $S(x)$ in place of $y$ - in spite of the restriction - we get :

> $\exists x (x \le S(x))$,

which is still true in $\mathbb N$ [to be precise, it is true for all values of $x$].

But try now with the formula :

> $\exists x (x = y)$.

Again, if we substitute $y$ with $0, 1, 2, \ldots$ we obtain the formulae :

> $\exists x (x = 0), \exists x (x = 1), \ldots$

which are still satisfiable in $\mathbb N$ : we can always find a "suitable" value for $x$.

What happens now with the "illegal" substitution of $S(x)$ in place of $y$ (recall that $S(x)$ "means" $x+1$) ? We get :

> > $\exists x (x = S(x))$

which is clearly *unsatisfiable* in $\mathbb N$.

*This is the 'intuition' behind the restriction regarding* substitution ...